# Is there keyboard shortcut for changing DEADLINE warning date?

Tags: org-mode

In org-mode, warning date for a TODO's DEADLINE can be designated by giving the `-` date.
For example,

```
DEADLINE: <2004-02-29 Sun -5d>
```

Is there any keyboard shortcut for changing this warning date descriptor?
Because, my current operation for changing this descriptor would be to
move the cursor into the timestamp and to edit it manually; it can be better, I think...

Comment: `C-c C-d` which invokes `org-deadline` should do the job

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan this is definitely the answer -- you should post it as such. To elaborate slightly, this prompts for the date/time using he standard popup. It will add a DEADLINE if there's not already one there, and edit the current one if there is. This is documented in the manual: http://orgmode.org/manual/Inserting-deadline_002fschedule.html

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan If I'm correct, the prompt invoked by `C-c C-d` is capable of only setting the date itself, not the warning descriptor... Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ah i'm sorry about the misunderstanding. I do not think it is possible to have warnings also when creating deadlines with `C-c C-d` (same with scheduling a repeating task). I think it has to be done manually.
Maybe someone who knows more about Org-mode can help.

Comment: In the event someone is motivated to write up a custom solution, here is a link to a thread where I wrote a related solution to set the repeater:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29399/specify-repeater-when-setting-deadline-for-org-mode-todo/29400  A similar approach can be used to increment/deincrement the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this can be helpful or not but, you can change it with holding shift and increasing or decreasing the number by up and down arrow. But for this the cursor has to be on top of the `-<number>d` section.

Answer (score 1):

Use the C-u C-u prefix!

***Example***

Set the warning period to 7 days before the deadline with

```
C-u C-u C-c C-d -7
```

As far as I can see this feature has not been documented yet in the info pages of Org mode.