# Specify repeater when setting deadline for org-mode TODO

Tags: org-mode

With point on a TODO item in an `.org` file, I can use `org-deadline` (`C-c C-d`) to insert a deadline for the TODO. **Is there any way to do this, and specify a repeater (e.g., `+1w`) at the same time?**

Currently, I add a deadline using the method described above, then navigate to the end of the timestamp and manually add the repeater to the stamp. It doesn't seem like it will be possible from the `org-deadline` UI, because in that context `+1w` represents a delta ("a week from...") rather than a repeating interval. I have also looked through the documentation, and tried searching Emacs for commands of the form `org*repeat*`, but haven't come up with anything yet. However, it seems like a fairly common task, so I assumed there would be a related command.

Comment: If it were me, I would add an additional optional argument to the tail end of arguments for `org-insert-time-stamp` to handle things like `+1w` and I would have that function let-bind `org-time-stamp-formats` to have both the `car` and `cdr` handle this new situation (if it exists) -- i.e., default `org-time-stamp-formats` when new situation does not exist.  I would modify `org-deadline` (and `org-schedule`) along with `org-add-planning-info` to account for the new situation.  And, then I would do some debugging to see what else gets broken in the process and fix it.  :)

Answer (score 4):

[See initial comment underneath the original question for a more robust idea that requires substantial hacking.]

```lisp
(defun my-org-deadline (arg &optional time repeat)
(interactive "P")
  (let ((org-time-stamp-formats
          (if repeat
            `(,(concat "<%Y-%m-%d %a " repeat ">") .
              ,(concat "<%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M " repeat ">"))
             org-time-stamp-formats)))
    (org-deadline arg time)))
```

**Example Usage**:  `(my-org-deadline nil "December 19, 2016 08:00" "+1w")`